# Azure Function Dependency Injection - Registering a Class that Depends on a Configuration Subsection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configuration, azure-functions

This is in an Azure Function.

Here's my whole Startup Class.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();
            //builder.Services.AddSingleton<MySystemMessage>(new MySystemMessage(configuration.GetSection("AzureFunctionsJobHost")));
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IMySystemMessage, MySystemMessage>();
        }
    }
```

I was registering a class as a singleton, and passing in a subsection of the configuration as a parameter to the constructor.  (see commented code)

I need to change this to a non-static object (see last line), but I don't see how I can get it to use the configuration subsection.

I tried getting the configuration subsection in all of the constructors where the configuration was injected, but there were too many places, it made the code messy, and there's also some common shared code where that would not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory delegate can be used when registering the service. You will have access to the built service provider to resolve any dependencies.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup {
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {            
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IMySystemMessage, MySystemMessage>(sp => {
            IConfiguration configuration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>();
            return new MySystemMessage(configuration.GetSection("AzureFunctionsJobHost"));
        });
    }
}
```

I would suggest using a strongly typed dependency that maps to the subsection. That way there is no need to be injecting messy subsection all over the place. You could also consider using the built-in Options pattern with `IOptions`

Comment: Thanks, after correcting many related issues in other parts of the application, I managed to get your solution working.  If you have some free time, I'd appreciate seeing more details on your additional suggestions, otherwise, it's working correctly now.